# macOS App Microphone Permission Issue: Manual Toggle in System Settings Not Recognized

Tags: swift, macos, permissions, microphone

I'm developing a macOS app and I'm trying to access the microphone without directly triggering the default permission dialog. Instead, I've managed to programmatically open the System Settings, specifically the `Privacy & Security -> Microphone section`, allowing users to manually grant permission.

However, there's an issue. Even after the user manually toggles on the microphone permission for my app in System Settings, the `AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .audio)` still returns `.notDetermined`.

To clarify, I'm avoiding the use of `AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .audio)` because it prompts the default permission dialog. But when I do use it, the app correctly recognizes changes in permission status. The problem arises only when trying to detect permission changes made directly from the System Settings.

[image]

Here is my code :

```swift
struct SystemSettingsHandler {
    static func openSystemSetting(for type: String) {
        guard type == "microphone" || type == "screen" else {
            return
        }
        
        let microphoneURL = "x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Microphone"
        let screenURL = "x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_ScreenCapture"
        let urlString = type == "microphone" ? microphoneURL : screenURL
        
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
        NSWorkspace.shared.open(url)
    }
}

    private func requestMicrophonePermission(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        switch AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .audio) {
        case .authorized:
            print("authorized")
            completion(true)
            
        case .notDetermined:
            print("notDetermined")
            AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .audio) { granted in
                if granted {
                    completion(granted)
                } else {
                    completion(granted)
                }
            }
            
        case .denied, .restricted:
            print("denied")
            SystemSettingsHandler.openSystemSetting(for: "microphone")
            completion(false)
            
        @unknown default:
            print("unknown")
            completion(false)
        }
    }
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: I doubt your be able to. I’m sure Apple has things to do when the dialog returns to actually give your app permission. You are skipping that step, even if you find a workaround I doubt it will pass AppStore checks and it will likely get patched on a future update. Also when accessing settings via the private keys is usually a deal breaker for Apple review too.

Comment: The documentation states: "Recording audio requires explicit permission from the user." `.notDetermined`: "A status that indicates the user hasn’t yet granted or denied authorization.". Does the permission dialog appear every time or just once?

Comment: @loremipsum Thank you for your input. I've seen the app that does it without showing the dialog. The app gets its necessary permissions only through opening the System Settings in which you mentioned that it would be a deal breaker for Apple review since it's accessing settings via the private keys.

Comment: @Willeke The permission dialog appears just once and it has to appear at least once for my app to function correctly. If I just open up the system settings and toggle the permissions without at least showing the permission dialog once, my app does not recognize the changes in permission status. This is very odd as I've seen the other app that functions correctly by only opening up the System Settings.

Comment: This isn't odd, it is what Apple requires: "explicit permission from the user". Are you sure the other app never displayed the dialog once? Is the app signed and sandboxed?

Comment: @Willeke I am 100% sure as I am currently using the app. It never displayed the dialog not even once. It gets its necessary permissions via the System Settings. How can I know if the app is signed and sandboxed? Is there a way to check?

Comment: @Willeke I've downloaded the app on the app's website in the form of .dmg

Comment: See [How do I find out what entitlements an app has?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52675/how-do-i-find-out-what-entitlements-an-app-has)

Comment: @Willeke I've checked it actually by opening up the app's Info.plist in Content directory. It has Privacy - Microphone Usage Description with String value which I obviously didn't get to see because like I said above, the app never even once opens up the dialog. It rather gets the necessary permissions via directing the user to System Settings -> Privacy & Security -> Microphone. Once the user toggles the permission to grant, it gets the permission and this part is very odd and bizarre as it is not achievable in my code base.